# Does 'evening and morning' in Genesis 1:5 indicate that 'Day' brackets (or includes) 'Night'?

Tags: genesis, hebrew

'Evening' in Hebrew is *ereb* which has four homonyms translated in the KJV as follows -

- 1) den, once
- 2) evening/even/eventide/night 124 times
- 3) mingled people 5 times
- 4) mixed multitude/woof/mixed 11 times

  [Young's Analytical].

Overall, there is a meaning of mixture in the 140 times of its usage - twilight, one might say.

'Morning' in Hebrew is *boqer* which is translated

- day/early/morning/morrow 201 times as one homonym
- and only one time as 'herdman', listed by Young as a homonym but perhaps only a metaphoric use in Amos (see footnote).

Thus 'morning' has no connotation of mixture, it is pure.

Thus the evening is twilight - daylight which is on the wane and has a shadow of night about it. It is a mixture descending into darkness.

But the morning is clear light and continues until the twilight again introduces a mix.

But between these two states is total darkness. Therefore, does the word 'Day' refer to the twilight and the clear morning light but, unspoken and without being remarked, the 'Night' is bracketed within it ?

So 'evening and morning' belong to the Day. That is to say the fact of an existing mixture, and its final resolution (by the separation) into a realm of pure Light - is, considered as a whole - a 'Day'.

In other words, does 'Day' mean a period of time in which there is a resolution from 'evening mixture' to 'daylight purity' ? Which period of time includes a period of darkness whilst the resolution is effected ?

Furthermore, all six days involve the resolution of things that are either separated one from the other - or something comes out of another thing, to stand as a separate thing.

So is that what the term 'Day' actually means - a phase in which something is resolved ? It is obscure, mixed ... and then all is resolved, clearly ?

And, further, notably, the seventh day is rest. All is resolved - there is no more to be done.

---

Footnote : Amos states, in 1:1, that he was among the herdmen (*noqed*).

But in Amos 7:14 he says further - I no prophet, neither I a prophet's son; but I a herdman (*boqer*) and a cultivator of sycamores: and the Lord took me from after the flock. [Literal rendering, adapted, from Young.]

Amos is taken from being a follower and becomes a new thing, a 'morning', resolved from the rest, to stand out, singularly.

He uses the word *boqer* metaphorically, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

"Day" as יום is 24-hour period (according to Mishna Zmanim its count from twilight to twilight). 
For light hebrew usually use אור.
Boqer in Amos is with diffrent niqud and although it's written the same they both got different origin (like זרע and לחם and alot other roots).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

In this coming time the Lord comes to open up our minds to the Scripture of Truth and it is His Light that dawns as the morning (the bright and morning star) within our very own obscured (darkened) hearts and is the witness of God within us that says that this is His Son speaking whom we are to listen to.

This dawning of the bright and morning star within our very own hearts is the “sign of the Son of man” who speaks from Heaven to us and we are to “take heed” on how we hear.

Some will take heed and hear and believe and some will not.

In this parable of the regeneration of man in Genesis chapter 1, the children of the Day will respond to the Light with light….with His righteousness…while the children of the Night will not.

> Genesis 1:3-5 KJV ***(3)  And God said, Let there be light: and there was
>   light.***

As shown from the Beginning, the believers will be divided from the unbelievers for what does light have in partnership with darkness?  (*2 Corinthians 6:14 - Be ye not unequally yoked together with unbelievers: for what fellowship hath righteousness with unrighteousness? and **what communion hath light with darkness?***)

> (4)  ***And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the
>   light from the darkness.***

God calls to the light “Day” and to the darkness He calls “Night”.

> (5)  ***And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night***.
>   And the evening and the morning were the first day.

The Lord comes to speak from Heaven to our hearing ears on a day we are not expecting.  The children of the Day are separate from the children of the Night in His Judgment as light has no communion with the darkness.

The children of the Light….the children of the Day…. will not be found “asleep” in the darkness to His righteousness as they will respond to the hearing of His voice (Let there be Light…and the Light shines within the heart) with good works (and the response to the Light is light – good works).  They will REMEMBER to do His will.

The children of the darkness will be found “asleep” to His righteousness in the Night and “drunk” on the wine of wrath in their unbelief of what they hear.  They will not believe and be full of wrath …speaking evil words in their contentions of what they hear the Spirit saying to the churches.  They will not remember to do His will.

Those of the Day will not be overtaken in that day when someone comes along to speak His words of life and spirit to their hearing ears.  They will remember to let brotherly love continue and will be found hospitable towards strangers and their words while those of the Night will be forgetful and not do those things.

> 1 Thessalonians 5:4-9 KJV (4)  *But ye, brethren, are not in darkness,
>   that that day should overtake you as a thief. (5)  Y**e are all the
>   children of light, and the children of the day: we are not of the
>   night, nor of darkness.** (6)  Therefore let us not sleep, as do others;
>   but let us watch and be sober. (7)  **For they that sleep sleep in the
>   night; and they that be drunken are drunken in the night**. (8)  **But let
>   us, who are of the day,** be sober, putting on the breastplate of faith
>   and love; and for an helmet, the hope of salvation. (9)  For God hath
>   not appointed us to wrath, but to obtain salvation by our Lord Jesus
>   Christ,*

The Light shines in the heart of those who will hear His words spoken in the Spirit of Truth.

Some will respond to the Light with light and will believe in what they hear….becoming children of Light… as they walk according to the Spirit in the Light. God is Light and in Him there is no darkness

Others will hear and not believe and be found walking in “darkness” still as they respond to His words with darkness:  hatred of their brothers who come to speak His words, envy, strife, wrath, contentions, etc.

> John 12:35-40 KJV (35)  ***Then Jesus said unto them, Yet a little while
>   is the light with you. Walk while ye have the light, lest darkness
>   come upon you:*** for he that walketh in darkness knoweth not whither he
>   goeth.

The Light shines within the heart and we are to believe in the Light so that we may be children of Light.

> (36)  ***While ye have light, believe in the light, that ye may be the
>   children of light.*** These things spake Jesus, **and departed, and did
>   hide himself** from them.

But to those who will not believe, the Light goes down within their hearts and disappears.  The darkness comes upon them as the “sun goes down upon their wrath”.

> (37)  *But though he had done so many miracles before them, **yet they
>   believed not on him:** (38)  That the saying of Esaias the prophet might
>   be fulfilled, which he spake, Lord, who hath believed our report? and
>   to whom hath the arm of the Lord been revealed?*

The judgment then is this:   those who have the Light go down within their own hearts will not be able to believe. They cannot then believe. They are of the "Night".

They are called the “Night” then and will not be able to understand His words as they “wander” in the darkness of the Night as judgment upon them.   The wicked shall not understand.

They will not respond to the Light with light.  They will not be able to enter in to understand the mysteries of the kingdom as they did not show that they know Him by doing His commandments at the most critical time of their lives:  at the hearing of His voice from Heaven speaking the knowledge of God….interpreting the Scriptures in their correct interpretation.   They are the “Night” then.

> (39)  ***Therefore they could not believe,*** because that Esaias said
>   again, (40)  He hath blinded their eyes, and hardened their heart;
>   that they should not see with their eyes, nor understand with their
>   heart, and be converted, and I should heal them.

In Beginning (Jesus Christ who is the Beginning of the creation of God) God created the heavens and the earth.

> Genesis 1: KJV (1)  **In the beginning God created the heaven and the
>   earth.**

The invisible things of Him from the creation of the world are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even his eternal power and Godhead; so that they are without excuse.

Mankind has only **to see the visible creation** to understand the invisible things of God but his foolish heart was darkened.

Now mankind **needs to hear** the knowledge of God as man’s foolish heart was darkened as he became vain in his imaginations.  He needs to be regenerated **by the hearing of His Word of Truth** spoken in the Spirit.   Mankind needs to be renewed in the spirit of his mind.

The earth became without form (without righteousness) and void….void of the knowledge of God…as men who professed themselves as “wise” became fools and their foolish heart was darkened.  Counsel in the heart of man is like deep water, but a man of intelligence will draw it out.

The heart of man has become foolish and his mouth speaks words of obscurity.  He does no righteousness.  The earth BECAME without form and void of understanding.  (*Romans 3: **There is no one righteous, not even one**. 11 **There is no one who understands**, no one who seeks God. 12All have turned away; **they have together become worthless**; there is no one who does good, not even one...*)

But, our God is merciful to mankind….His creation…as the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.  Proverbs 18:4 - The words of a man's mouth are as deep waters, and the wellspring of wisdom as a flowing brook.

Holy men of God speak His words as they are moved by the Spirit so that the Light  will shine in the hearts of others (let there be Light) who will hear and believe in His words (and there was light).

> (2)  *And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon
>   the face of the deep. **And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the
>   waters**.*

Mankind has been foolish, disobedient, deceived, hating one another, etc.  The earth became without form….without His righteousness…and void of His knowledge as none understands and all have gone out of the Way of righteousness.

> Titus 3:3-7 KJV (3)  ***For we ourselves also were sometimes foolish,
>   disobedient, deceived, serving divers lusts and pleasures, living in
>   malice and envy, hateful, and hating one another.***

But the kindness and love of God our Savior appears towards man as He commands the Light to shine in the darkness of our own hearts.

> (4)  ***But after that the kindness and love of God our Saviour toward
>   man appeared,***

Genesis 1 is the parable of the regeneration of man.  It is only by His mercy does He save us from the current condition (of being without form…without His righteousness…. and void of His knowledge) by the washing of REGENERATION and renewing of the Holy Spirit.

> (5)  *Not by works of righteousness which we have done, **but according
>   to his mercy he saved us, by the washing of regeneration, and renewing
>   of the Holy Ghost;** (6)  Which he shed on us abundantly through Jesus
>   Christ our Saviour; (7)  That being justified by his grace, we should
>   be made heirs according to the hope of eternal life.*

The “evening and the morning” in Genesis 1 speaks of  the condition of the heart….the place of the darkened/obscured heart ….where the light breaks forth within as the dawning morning when one hears the true Word of God as men are moved by the Holy Spirit to speak.

The light shines in a “dark place”…an obscure place….the shadiness of the heart.   The more we listen, the more knowledge we receive as the dawning morning progresses into the Light of seven days where there is no more darkness within the heart: Day 1,2,3...7.

The evening fades away as the Light grows brighter and brighter until there is no more “evening”  in the 7th day.

We are to “take heed” on how we hear as we see the witness of God (about His Son speaking to us )….the morning Light arising within our very own hearts.

The Hebrew for “morning” is “boqer” and comes from the root “baqar” which means  properly, “to plough, or (generally) break forth, i.e. (figuratively) to inspect, admire, care for, consider (make) inquire (-ry), (make) search, seek out”.

We are to then “take heed” (baqar)….to inspect, admire, care for, seek out…to that “morning light” (boqer) arising within our own heart (as unto a light shining in a dark place) so that we are given more Light.  The "day star" in the heart = the bright and morning star = the sign of the Son of man who speaks to us from Heaven as He interprets the Scriptures to us.

> 2 Peter 1:19-21 KJV (19)  *We have also a more sure word of prophecy;
>   whereunto ye do well that **ye take heed, as unto a light that shineth
>   in a dark place, until the day dawn, and the day star arise in your
>   hearts:** (20)  Knowing this first, that no prophecy of the scripture is
>   of any private interpretation. (21)  For the prophecy came not in old
>   time by the will of man: but holy men of God spake as they were moved
>   by the Holy Ghost.*

We are to “take heed”  on how we hear and more shall be given.  The Light shall grow brighter and brighter unto the full knowledge of God shines without any obscurity within.

> Mark 4:24-25 KJV (24)  *And he said unto them, **Take heed what ye hear:**
>   with what measure ye mete, it shall be measured to you: and unto you
>   that hear shall more be given. (25)  **For he that hath, to him shall be
>   given: and he that hath not, from him shall be taken even that which
>   he hath.***

The heart is an obscure place where we only know in part.

> 1 Corinthians 13:9-12 KJV (9)  **For we know in part, and we prophesy in
>   part.**

But when that which is complete is come, then that which is in part shall be done away as the darkness fades away and disappears from within the heart.   We are to be men in understanding and put away the thoughts of a child.

> (10)  ***But when that which is perfect is come, then that which is in
>   part shall be done away.*** (11)  When I was a child, I spake as a child,
>   I understood as a child, I thought as a child: but when I became a
>   man, I put away childish things. (12)  For now we see through a glass,
>   darkly; but then face to face: n**ow I know in part; but then shall I
>   know even as also I am known**.

God commands the Light to shine out of darkness (shadiness, obscurity) to give the Light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ.  The Light shines within our own obscured hearts when one hears the words of the Lord spoken by men who are moved by the Spirit (the Spirit of God moved upon the “waters”….the words spoken by men).

It is the Light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ as we show we know Him by having love for another.  The only way to enter in to that understanding is to do His commands.

> 2 Corinthians 4:6-7 KJV (6)  ***For God, who commanded the light to shine
>   out of darkness, hath shined in our hearts, to give the light of the
>   knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ***.

The Light shining in the obscured heart is of the power of God and not of the speaker of His words.  We receive the testimony of men but the witness of God (the Light shining within our own hearts) is greater.

> (7)  *But we have this treasure in earthen vessels, **that the excellency
>   of the power may be of God, and not of us.***

The more we hear, the more the Light shines and brightens our hearts until the Day is established.  We, the children of the Light shining in the obscured heart, become children of the Day where there is no darkness left within the heart.

> Proverbs 4:18 ***And the path of the righteous is as a shining light,
>   Going and brightening till the day is established,***

The path of the righteous is a as a shining Light within the heart....while the way of the wicked is as darkness.  The do NOT KNOW at what they stumble as the wicked shall not have understanding.  "Night" shall be unto them as they will not enter in to His knowledge.

> Proverbs 4:19-22 KJV (19)  *T**he way of the wicked is as darkness: they
>   know not at what they stumble.** (20)  **My son, attend to my words;
>   incline thine ear unto my sayings**. (21)  Let them not depart from
>   thine eyes; keep them in the midst of thine heart. (22)  For they are
>   life unto those that find them, and health to all their flesh.*

---

4/21/19

Added summary:

To summarize to answer the question, this is a metaphor for the coming division of the believers of the Light (the children of the Day) from the unbelievers (those of the “Night”).   This division starts at the house of God in the churches of men.

The “evening and the morning” belongs only to those of the Day and not the Night in a spiritual sense.  He calls those of the Light (as they react to the Light with light....with His righteousness) to the Day (to complete understanding)  but those who will continue to act in darkness to the “Night”….to the Night of completely not understanding.

Those of the “darkness” (to be dark…withholding light) will continue to walk in the darkness  (envy, strife, contentions, hatred, wrath, etc) as they will not show brotherly love and will contend with the Light of the knowledge of the glory of God.   They will not be found reacting to the Light with light…with His righteousness.

They are judged as those of the “Night” where they shall not have any understanding…and  what little they knew also gets removed.  The wicked shall not understand (the “Night” of not understanding) as they will rage against what they hear.

The Hebrew word for “Night” is “Laylah”….. **“a twist” away of the Light.**

The Light of the knowledge of God gets removed from the heart of those who will continue to behave in “darkness”….wickedness.  **It twists away out of their hearts and cannot stay** even when they hear His words…ever learning but never able to come to the knowledge of the Truth.  They will instead be found resisting what they hear.

> 2 Timothy 3:7-8 KJV (7)  ***Ever learning, and never able to come to the
>   knowledge of the truth.*** (8)  Now as Jannes and Jambres withstood
>   Moses, so do these also resist the truth: men of corrupt minds,
>   reprobate concerning the faith.

The gloom of darkness is reserved for them "for ever" as God judges them as "Night" and they wander as planets (wandering stars) without understanding His knowledge.

> Jude 1:13 KJV (13)  Raging waves of the sea, foaming out their own
>   shame; wandering stars, to whom is reserved the blackness of darkness
>   for ever.

They will not enter in to KNOW the mysteries of the kingdom of Heaven.  It is not given to them to understand.  They are the "Night".

> Matthew 13:11-12 KJV (11)  *He answered and said unto them, **Because it
>   is given unto you to know the mysteries of the kingdom of heaven, but
>   to them it is not given**.*

And even what Light they may have gets removed from their hearts in the Judgment.

They are of the “Night”….Hebrew Layla…as the Light twists away out of their hearts and leaves them in a state of total lack of the knowledge of God.   The Night is absent of the Light completely.  The wicked shall not understand.

> (12)  *For whosoever hath, to him shall be given, and he shall have
>   more abundance: **but whosoever hath not, from him shall be taken away
>   even that he hath**.*

They will speak evil of those things (spiritual things) that they know not.

> Jude 1:10 KJV (10)  ***But these speak evil of those things which they
>   know not:*** but what they know naturally, as brute beasts, in those
>   things they corrupt themselves.

The natural man (the man who continues to sow after the flesh and not after the Spirit) cannot understand the things of the Spirit of God that moves men to speak His words (the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters….the words of men who speak as they are moved by His Spirit).

They are spiritually discerned….that is, only by sowing after the Spirit can one understand the things of the Spirit of God.   If we sow after the flesh as the natural man does, then there is no way to enter in to understand.   Only by sowing according to the Spirit can one understand.

> 1 Corinthians 2:14 KJV (14)  *But the natural man receiveth not the
>   things of the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him:
>   neither can he know them, **because they are spiritually discerned**.*

The “evening and the morning” speaks of the once-darkened heart that the Light shines in and belongs to the children of the Day only (and not of those of the “Night”) as the Light within them progressively grows brighter and brighter until there is no more “evening” within them.

The righteous will understand more and grow in the knowledge of the Lord Jesus who comes to speak His heavenly knowledge through the interpretation of the Scriptures.

They will not be led away with the error of the wicked who will rage against what they hear:  the hearing of the heavenly interpretation of the Scriptures by our Lord Jesus.   The wicked shall not understand.

> 2 Peter 3:17-18 KJV (17)  *Ye therefore, beloved, seeing ye know these
>   things before, **beware lest ye also, being led away with the error of
>   the wicked, fall from your own stedfastness**.*

The righteous shall grow in grace and in the knowledge of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ (the Light of the knowledge of the glory of God shining within our hearts) while the wicked shall be outside in the "darkness".

> (18)  **But grow in grace, and in the knowledge of our Lord and Saviour
>   Jesus Christ.** To him be glory both now and for ever. Amen.

The “evening” (Hebrew:  ereb- dusk)  speaks of us only knowing in part but also do not know in part.  This mingling eventually gets done away as the Light of the knowledge of God increases more and more until there is no more “evening”.  It will shine as the light of 7 days.  There is no “evening and morning” on the seventh day.

> Isaiah 30:26 KJV (26)  *Moreover the light of the moon shall be as the
>   light of the sun, and the light of the sun shall be sevenfold, **as the
>   light of seven days, in the day** that the LORD bindeth up the breach of
>   his people, and healeth the stroke of their wound*.

Everyone that has (works of God's righteousness to show in response to His words)shall be given more knowledge while those that do not have shall be taken away even that which he has.

> Matthew 25:29-30 KJV (29)  **For unto every one that hath shall be
>   given, and he shall have abundance: but from him that hath not shall
>   be taken away even that which he hath.**

The unprofitable servant is thrown into "outer darkness"...a complete lack of knowing of the knoweldge of God that he has rejected.   Instead of receiving His words with joy and belief, the wicked will rage against it (gnashing of teeth) and their own evil words will come back upon their own heads to torment them (weeping).

> (30)  **And cast ye the unprofitable servant into outer darkness: there
>   shall be weeping and gnashing of teeth.**

His servants will be found doing His righteousness at the hearing of His knowledge in this coming time. But the wicked will do wickedly in their rejection of what they will hear Him speaking.

> Isaiah 65:12-16 KJV (12)  *Therefore will I number you to the sword,
>   and ye shall all bow down to the slaughter: because when I called, ye
>   did not answer; **when I spake, ye did not hear; but did evil before
>   mine eyes, and did choose that wherein I delighted not**.*

His servants will eat what is presented to them.  They will drink in what the Spirit is saying. But the wicked will reject it and go hungry and thirsty spiritually speaking.  His servants will rejoice in what they hear but the wicked shall be found ashamed at what they hear.

> (13)  *Therefore thus saith the Lord GOD, **Behold, my servants shall
>   eat, but ye shall be hungry: behold, my servants shall drink, but ye
>   shall be thirsty: behold, my servants shall rejoice, but ye shall be
>   ashamed:***

His servants will sing for joy of heart at what they hear while the wicked will lament it and be enraged at it.

> (14)  ***Behold, my servants shall sing for joy of heart, but ye shall
>   cry for sorrow of heart, and shall howl for vexation of spirit.*** (15) 
>   And ye shall leave your name for a curse unto my chosen: for the Lord
>   GOD shall slay thee, and call his servants by another name: (16)  That
>   he who blesseth himself in the earth shall bless himself in the God of
>   truth; and he that sweareth in the earth shall swear **by the God of
>   truth;** because the former troubles are forgotten, and because they are
>   hid from mine eyes.

Comment: Interesting exegesis, but I’m not sure you answered the question.